# Varnish plus cloudflare

Tags: magento, caching, cdn, varnish, cloudflare

I found this article while searching if there is any VCL tweak that needs to be done while using varnish and cloudflare. I have currently not included the below tweaks suggested by cloudflare. Can anyone suggest if this is really needed?

[Cloudflare varnish VCL configuration](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169376-Can-I-use-Cloudflare-and-Varnish-together-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a *must do*, but it may be a good idea to strip not-needed cookies, so that you can cache as much as you can.
Perhaps try with and without the snippet and check which behaviour works best for your use case.